# No title in ContentPage

Tags: maui

In .Net MAUI, when I navigate to another ContentPage with Navigation.PushAsync, the next page won't have a title. It shows a back button at top left instead. How do I show my title without back button?
To make it clear, when started, my MainPage has a title visible in title bar. There won't be title when I navigate to the same MainPage with Navigation.PushAsync.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 with .Net 7.0. Test is done on a USB attached Android device.

Had tried Shell.TitleView, NavigationPage.HasBackButton with no luck.

Comment: Why don't you use an absolute route URI such as `GoToAsync("//NextPage")`? Read more about absolute route URI in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link? I will help you to check why it's not working on your side.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT, I am not too familiar with the public github. But it's easy to reproduce. Just create a new .Net MAUI project. In the sample OnCounterClicked event method, make the method async and add 3 lines to navigate to the same page.
var mainPage = new MainPage();
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
await Navigation.PushAsync(navigationPage);
When click the button, it navigates to the same page but with no title.

Comment: @StephenQuan, thank you for the comment. I didn't know that there's another way of navigation. It looks so different from what I have learned so far. I will have a look later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to .xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp4.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False"/>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
.....
```

Then use `Navigation.PushAsync` directly instead:

```cs
private void OnCounterClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;

    if (count == 1)
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
    else
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

    SemanticScreenReader.Announce (CounterBtn.Text);

    // var mainPage = new MainPage();
    // var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    // await Navigation.PushAsync(navigationPage);

    Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage ());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Need to study more about what is the NavigationPage for.